# Stored procedure not inserting into a table when called from a view - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EXPORT_SALES
AS
    -- insert invoice numbers into zInvoices table for use later
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO zInvoices 
        SELECT 
            Orders.InvoiceNo 
        FROM 
            Orders
        WHERE 
            (Orders.PostStatus = 2
             AND Orders.VoidFlag = 0
             AND Orders.LastModDate > Orders.ReplicationDateTime);

    -- get recordset of data to return to view
    SELECT NewId() AS IRN, CompanyName
    FROM Companies;
END
```

View:

```
ALTER VIEW mvuEXPORT_SALES 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM openquery([local], 'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC DBName.user.EXPORT_SALES');
GO
```

If I run the stored procedure, it inserts into the zInvoices table and returns the recordset with the Id and CompanyName. When I run it from the view; it returns the recordset with the Id and CompanyName...but it doesn't insert into the zInvoices table.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A view definition can only have a `Single Select` statement. You cannot execute a procedure inside a view check MSDN for more limitations for SQL Server views.

Comment: You can execute a stored procedure within a view as long as the stored procedure return a recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this see anything returns:

```
SELECT Orders.InvoiceNo FROM Orders
PostStatus = 2
AND VoidFlag = 0
AND LastModDate > ReplicationDateTime
```

Comment: if nothing returns, then you have to modify that insert query first before you could let the sp insert some records

Comment: Long - Yes it does return records...and the view returns records.